# In the history of the development of the standard model was there a version in which quark-antiquark pairs or flux tubes were the fundamental particle

Tags: string-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, mesons, confinement

Based on the observations of color confinement and no free quarks, I'm wondering if instead of a having quarks as fundamental particles, during development of the Standard Model was there ever a version of the theory where quark-antiquark pairs or a flux tubes were the fundamental particles?

It seems that if we can't actually truly split a quark-antiquark pair (i.e. because if the distance is large enough, new pairs form reducing the distance), then it seems like it could have been considered that the "quark-antiquark pair" object or the flux tubes were the fundamental, basically indivisible particle.

Was there a version of the theory out there like this / has it been tried?

Comment: 1. I don't understand how you think this theory would model hadrons, which aren't pairs but *triplets* of quarks. 2. If the idea that we can treat particles as fundamental just because their components (quarks) can't exist freely were true, then why do you think we introduced quarks in the first place?

Comment: I think it's very strange to propose/ask about an alternative theory when you don't understand how we arrived at the mainstream theory we currently use in the first place. If you just want to know why we use a theory in which single quarks are fundamental even if they can't exist freely, why don't you just ask about *that*?

Comment: Where did I propose an alternate theory?  I asked if there was an alternate theory.  There's tons of alternate theories out there for a wide range of mainstream physics.  Why do you keep saying I'm proposing a theory?

Comment: In the language  used for physics, a fundamental particle has no components, If it has components it is not fundamental.

Comment: Of course there is no such theory (any well meaning reader would assume you already know this). Convince the reader how you explain the valence parton distribution data in such a theory. Your second paragraph all but argues hadrons are fundamental?!

Comment: Amazing the responses this question generated.  Really does not paint a nice picture of this community.  I have very very limited idea of how the standard model developed and/or other alternatives along the way.  Seems totally reasonable to ask about.

Comment: Being labeled off topic is the chef's kiss on top.  There are tons of questions on here about speculative physics beyond the standard model, behind general relativity that are considered perfectly acceptable.  Unreal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is not totally ridiculous. Quarks are a lot like poles of a magnet. They don't exist on their own, but magnets do. Just like quarks, new magnetic poles appear in pairs when you try to separate an existing pair by pulling the magnet apart. The 'poles' are called quark and antiquark. Nature also offers objects with three poles, now the poles are called coloured quarks. You might call these two-pole and three-pole objects basic, to avoid the word elementary. No new theory here, just a way of looking at the respected standard model!

Comment: "No new theory here, just a way of looking at the respected standard model!" one with substantially more elementary particles and substantially less predictive power. You might as well call it a particle zoo.

Comment: At least the *phenomenon* is very elementary, or basic, or universal or whatever choice of words you prefer.

Comment: You are providing the low-rent science-journalistic "intuition" on color confinement through color flux tubes. Diquarks the OP is profferring are not covered by it.  Until the OP defines "fundamental", it's all idle talk.

Comment: dllahr, in the nice (low-rent?) article http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2017/12/get-your-protons-right.html Sabine Hossenfelder writes "This distribution of flux tubes has nothing to do with the flavor of the quarks, meaning it’s the same for the proton and the neutron and all other particles composed of three quarks" So, kind of fundamental? Then someone asks "Would it be feasible to see the flux tubes themselves as the basic 'particle' making up hadrons?" Hossenfelder's answer is "No, the flux-tubes are not fermionic." My interpretation: fundamental yes, particle no.

Comment: Or you might skip misleading English words and just coin a word for these particles. "Hadrons" has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 1):

No. By definition of the meaning of "pair of particles".

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account the fact that *particle* is a very nebulous concept in quantum field theory.